# How to create a new field that returns true or false on the difference between two records using row_number

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a railroad crossing database table that has columns `CrossingID`, `ReasonID`, and `LastUpdated` on top of a lot of additional columns.

Each `CrossingID` has several records going back through time for each time the database was updating that crossing. I want to take the latest two records per `CrossingID`, order them by `LastUpdated`, and create a new field that spots any differences between the other fields and returns a true or false.

I figured out how to do the groupings with row_number and using a with statement as I just do not know how to create the checking field for any differences. Here is what I got so far:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY crossingid ORDER BY lastupdated DESC) AS RowNo, 
        crossingid, lastupdated, reportstatus, reasonid
    FROM
        statecrossingdata_5year
)
SELECT
    crossingid, lastupdated, rowno, reportstatus, reasonid
FROM
    cte 
WHERE
    rowno <= 2 
ORDER BY 
    crossingid, rowno
```

The Railroad database is public records and can be found here: https://safetydata.fra.dot.gov/OfficeofSafety/publicsite/DownloadCrossingInventoryData.aspx

Comment: You have a _table_ with _columns_, not a database with fields.

Comment: If you have a database, it has *tables*. As for the data, please don't ask us to download a database from an unknown source (even if that domain is a `.gov` domain). Put the **relevant** data into the question in a consumable format; preferable DDL and DML statements, or at worst well formatted tabular `text`.

Comment: Your probably going to need to self-join that CTE.

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY crossingid ORDER BY lastupdated DESC) AS RowNo, 
        crossingid, lastupdated, reportstatus, reasonid
    FROM
        statecrossingdata_5year
),
CTE2 as
(
SELECT
    crossingid, lastupdated, rowno, reportstatus, reasonid
FROM
    cte 
WHERE
    rowno <= 2 
)

SELECT x.*,
CASE WHEN x.reasonID = y.reasonID THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END
FROM CTE2 x
INNER JOIN CTE2 y
ON x.crossingID = y.crossingID
WHERE X.rowno = 2 AND y.rowno = 1
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work as I still need a means to only select the top 2 records per crossingid and compare those.

Comment: The order by clause in CTE2 is giving an error since a TOP clause isn't being used.

Comment: @benfardot You should be able to correct for that. CTE2 doesn't really do anything useful at this point. You could simply remove the order by clause from CTE2. You encourage others to help by providing a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). That provides everyone with a schema and sample data that can be used to understand your issue and experiment with code.

Comment: The logical alternative to `X.rowno > y.rowno` is `x.rowno = 2 and y.rowno = 1`. Hopefully that makes the self-join logic more "visible". Note that the case expression likely does not meet your definition of "differences" but you should be able to expand that for your purposes.

Comment: Yes, I did some copying and pasting to provide a short answer.  I have updated it to remove the ORDER BY and also edited the join logic as suggested.